# Djano first project errors

Tags: python, django

I am following this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

### I have seen many post referring to problems with getting djano and virtualenv set up. I have tried a lot of solutions to get everything working properly. However, I have been going in circles and i'm not sure why I cant proceed past: python manage.py runserver.

OS: macos version: 10.15.4 and have python 3.7.7 /

Python version : 3.7.7
python -m django --version : 3.0.6

### I used homebrew to install python

I have virtualenv working properly. Below is the error I keep getting.

(env) user@Shadow-Keeper mysite % python manage.py runserver

### /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Below are the file contents im working in

(env) user@Shadow-Keeper mysite % ls
manage.py   mysite

(env) user@Shadow-Keeper mysite % ls
**init**.py asgi.py     settings.py urls.py     wsgi.py

Comment: Which "mysite" directory are you in when you run the command?  The outer one or the inner one?  Make sure you're in the outer one where manage.py lives.

Comment: I just tried it again.... and now its working.. ooooofffff

Comment: Glad it's working.

Comment: To know if you are in correct directory, you can check if the directory where you are running the command has manage.py file.

Comment: What I have learned is if you are not careful you can have different versions installed which can cause conflicts. I believe that was the issue for me....before I posted here I fixed a few paths for python.